# Android Error loading image view

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, imageview, bitmapfactory

I am trying to load an image in my imageview but it does not load any image for the link.
The link has the image but I still get empty blank space.

```
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
    }
       protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
         try {
               String url = "http://www.learn2crack.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/node-cover-720x340.png";
               URL urlurl = new URL(url);
               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
      return bitmap;
       }
       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
         if(image != null){
           img.setImageBitmap(image);
         }else{
           Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Image Does Not exist or Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
       }
   }
```

XML

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
         />
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the logcat stacktrace you have a network on mainthread exception becasue you are doing a network task on the 'main' thread which is also called the gui thread. You need to use an AsyncTask for this.

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... args) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        return bmp;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
             //here do stuff with your bitmap data, also here you can interact with the gui
        }
    }
```

Also I recommend using an Image downloading library to download images off the web. They make it really easy to download images and you dont have to worry a lot about the tiny details.